# My app version2 is working fine but on updating the version1 with version2 the app is crashing, with below report:

Tags: android

**here is my error log**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.campaign/com.ui.MainActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 34 path $.aEl
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2488)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5442)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
    Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was NUMBER at line 1 column 34 path $.aEl
        at com.google.gson.internal.a.i$a.b(SourceFile:200)
        at com.google.gson.d.a(SourceFile:810)
        at com.google.gson.d.a(SourceFile:775)
        at com.google.gson.d.a(SourceFile:724)
        at com.google.gson.d.b(SourceFile:696)
        at com.gamooz.model.Book.cS(SourceFile:275)
        at com.gamooz.e.a.Y(SourceFile:341)
        at com.gamooz.e.a.aa(SourceFile:367)
        at com.gamooz.ui.fragment.o.hF(SourceFile:202)
        at com.gamooz.ui.fragment.o.onResume(SourceFile:270)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.aJ(SourceFile:2005)
        at android.support.v4.app.n.a(SourceFile:1057)
        at android.support.v4.app.n.a(SourceFile:1197)
        at android.support.v4.app.n.a(SourceFile:1179)
        at android.support.v4.app.n.dispatchResume(SourceFile:2001)
        at android.support.v4.app.k.dispatchResume(SourceFile:187)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(SourceFile:426)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:415)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(SourceFile:138)
        at android.app.Activity.performResu`enter code here`me(Activity.java:6403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3099)
```

Comment: it's an error in `MainActivity()` mostly in `onResume()` as log says `com.campaign/com.ui.MainActivity` it's about JSON expecting a JSON array but finds a number. post the relevant code from that activity

Comment: kindly post the code of MainActivity.java

Answer (score -2):

The error occurred due to the library Conflict that i was using in version 1 and version 2 of my app. I don't know the reason of conflict but re-adding library to my project worked for me. Now on update app is not crashing.